# Split HTML table in multiple tables

Tags: html, css

I have this task to create a responsive `HTML/CSS` table. When on mobile, columns are split in 3 tables while rows are kept.

How can I create this split version on mobile. Or should I use CSS grid for this?

Desktop version of table:

[image: 1]

This is how mobile version of table should look like:

[image: 2]

Comment: That's why tables aren't good for responsiveness and you should rather look into css-grids for something like this.

Comment: Try reading this short blog. i think this is what you asked for. [https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/](daLink)

Comment: @9841pratik This is what I looked for, thanks! <3

Comment: to split your table into multiple tables, you can use grid to reorder things and if you keep the table html markup, it will require to use display:contents too where the support is less than grid. best is to use another markup that remains coherent or make a few tables that might float side by side and wrap  to next line once needed. how ever , i'd rethink the HTML structure .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use media queries in CSS to make the table responsive and use classes. I personally would recommend a CSS framework for this like Bootstrap, Tailwind, Bulma or Semantic UI but you'll need to understand media queries for that.

You can create classes that will respond to change the width of the table body depending on where they are placed.

```
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

[Media Queries Refrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)